# Gripper penetrates object in Gazebo，why？

Tags: gazebo, gripper, collision-object

I used ros-melodic and gazebo version 11.13.0.
I used this gripper plugin [enter link description here](https://github.com/JenniferBuehler/gazebo-pkgs)

When the clamping jaw is closed, the terminal prompts that the object has been grasped, but the clamping jaw remains closed until it penetrates the object. Why is this?

[image]

The object is defined by myself, the following is its description.
[image]
[image]

Has anyone encountered this situation? Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

Comment: Please edit your post and tell us what Operating System you are using, and which version of gazebo are you using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding them now.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a collision error. If this has not already been done, check the "boundingObject" of your pliers and the object you want to retrieve with it, if one of the two is not correct then it is normal that they cross each other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t think this is the reason. This problem still occurs when I use other conventional objects. As for the clamps, I use the ones from the open source warehouse. There is no problem with the collision properties. Are there other reasons that may cause this? This situation?

Answer (score 0):

In gazebo, many gripper models do not use friction to "hold onto" an object. I assume that this is because it's extremely difficult to get it to work as expected.

Instead, the model uses a trick: either 1) temporarily create a joint between the gripper and the held-object, or 2) each simulation timestep, move the held-object to be near the gripper coordinates. For (2), it would not surprise me if collision-detect was also disabled (to avoid oscillation issues.) For the visual, you can adjust the grippers so it looks natural, but the actual amount of closure doesn't matter to the simulation.

Another thing to be aware of: in gazebo, the links on each side of a joint may never report collision (maybe depends on joint type?) This will matter if (1) is being used.